# Passing Acknowledgment to a spring KafkaListener consumer method

Tags: java, spring-kafka

I am trying to turn off auto committing in kafka, and instead do it manually. To that end, in my `application.properties` I have set `spring.kafka.properties.enable.auto.commit=false`

I also currently have a method with the following header:

```
@KafkaListener(id="${"+ KafkaConfiguration.APP_REQUEST_ID +"}", topics = "${"+KafkaConfiguration.PPA_REQUEST_TOPIC +"}")
public void receive(@Payload String message,
                    @Headers MessageHeaders headers)
```

My understanding is that in order to manually commit I need access to the `Acknowledgement` object, which would be passed in as a parameter to my `receive()` method. My question: if I change the header to

```
@KafkaListener(id="${"+ KafkaConfiguration.APP_REQUEST_ID +"}", topics = "${"+KafkaConfiguration.APP_REQUEST_TOPIC +"}")
public void receive(@Payload String message,
                    @Headers MessageHeaders headers,
                    Acknowledgment acknowledgment)
```

Will the `Acknowledgment` automatically be passed in, or are there other changes I need to make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, that way an `Acknowledgment` instance would be passed into your listener method. after successful processing of the received message you should call `acknowledgement.acknowledge();` (only needed if you want to manually ack)

I'd also switch to `MANUAL` ackmode and turn off auto-commit (what you already did), e.g. by providing a custom Spring Boot configuration class - maybe also configurable via `application.properties`:

```
@Configuration
class KafkaConfiguration {

        @Bean
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {

            final Map<String, Object> consumerProperties = kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties();
            consumerProperties.put(ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);

            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
            factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(MANUAL);

            return factory;
        }
    }
}
```

If you do NOT want to manually acknowledge then a different ackmode might be more convenient and a better fit:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/listener/ContainerProperties.AckMode.html

`AckMode.RECORD` is quite comfortable, since the Kafka record that was passed into your listener method will be automatically be acked if your listener's method implementation completes successfully (no exception is thrown).

Comment: I am having problems with AckMode.RECORD and isAckOnError false, if shutdown application the offset is not re-delivered. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, you do not need to pass `Acknowledgment`, it is part of the received message.

As per the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#kafka-listener-annotation)

> When using manual **AckMode**, you can also provide the listener with the **Acknowledgment**. The following example also shows how to use a different container factory.

```
@KafkaListener(id = "cat", topics = "myTopic",
          containerFactory = "kafkaManualAckListenerContainerFactory")
public void listen(String data, Acknowledgment ack) {
    ...
    ack.acknowledge();
}
```

From [@KafkaListener](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/annotation/KafkaListener.html) documentation:

Annotated methods are allowed to have flexible signatures similar to what MessageMapping provides, that is

- ConsumerRecord to access to the raw Kafka message
- Acknowledgment to manually ack
- @Payload-annotated method arguments including the support of validation
- @Header-annotated method arguments to extract a specific header value, defined by KafkaHeaders
- @Headers-annotated argument that must also be assignable to Map for getting access to all headers.
- MessageHeaders arguments for getting access to all headers.
- MessageHeaderAccessor for convenient access to all method arguments.

Answer (score 0):

What if we want to pass in a spring managed bean via method injection? Im trying to pass in a service class via method injection to a kafka listener -

```
private fun defaultListener(payload: ByteArray, @Headers messageHeaders: MessageHeaders, ack: Acknowledgment, callbackService: CallbackService) {
 // Do something
}
```

I get the following exception -

```
org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot handle message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from [[B] to [com.test.kafka-demo.service.CallbackService]
```

Works fine if i make the dependent service class Autowired.